# What is wrong with my do...while logic, and continue logic?

Tags: c++, random, do-while

I'm new to stackoverflow, and also somewhat new to programming, so please don't mind my poor formatting of the code. I have two problems with my code.

1. My continue statement, which I'm using to continue the loop if the player types 'y' or 'Y', doesn't work. It terminates the program after *only* getting the guess correctly, which leads me to:

2.My continue counter goes past 0 without stopping, and I just can't see my error in the logic of the program.

I can't see the problems with my logic.

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <random>

    using namespace std;

    int getNumber(); //random number prototype
    double getScore(); //gets score
    int chances = 7; //chances to guess with
    int main()
    {
    int guess = 0, 
        random;
    char retry = 'y'; //initialize retry to 'y'
    cout << "This is a random number guessing game. " << "You will be guessing between 1-100."
     << "You have 7 chances. Good luck! \n \n" << endl;


    random = getNumber(); //give the function a variable

  do
  {

    cout << random << "\n" << "\n";
    chances--;

    cout << "Enter your guess: ";
    cin >> guess;

        if (guess == random)
        {
            cout << "You have won the game! " << "Your score was: " << getScore();

            cout << "Would you like to retry? (Y or N): ";
            cin >> retry;

            if (retry == 'y' || retry == 'Y')
            {
                chances = 7;
                guess = 0;
                getNumber();
                continue; //player can retry the game
            }
            else if (chances == 0)
            {
                cout << "You have no chances left. Retry? (Y or N): ";
                    cin >> retry;
                if (retry == 'y' || retry == 'Y')
                {
                    chances = 7;
                    guess = 0;
                    getNumber();
                    continue;
                }
            }

                return 0;
        }
        else if (guess != random)
            cout << "You got it wrong. \n" << "You have: " << chances << " chances left" << endl << endl;
        else
            cout << "Incorrect Input. Please type a number." << endl << endl;
   } while (guess != random);


return 0;
}

 int getNumber()
    {
     unsigned seed = time(0); //seed the random number
     srand(seed);

     int randNum = rand() % 10 + 1; //random number in the range of 1-10
     return randNum;
    }
```

Comment: I do mind your poor formatting. Being new does not prevent you from spending some time and effort to format your code nicely. You can look at any number of existing, successful questions for examples. Stack Overflow has an excellent live post preview, so you can spend as much time as you need to make the post look good.

Comment: `if(retry=='y' || 'Y')` this doesnt do what you think it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll wanna take a look at [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/continue)

Your `continue` statement is jumping to the end and checking the condition, `guess != random`, which evaluates to false and exits the `do while`. What you need to do is reset guess to a value such as 0 so that the condition does evaluate to `true`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I couldn't see what was going on. I didn't know I had to reset the guess as well. Is the reason why I had to reset it because when it continued, it'd check if guess was equal to random, and since the player got it right, it would automatically be false, exiting the while?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> if (retry == 'y' || 'Y')
> ```

This is incorrect logic, which is why your code does not work the way you want it to. You want it to be:

```
if (retry == 'y' || retry == 'Y')
```

Fix this logic error in your other if-else statements as well.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even realize that. I edited my code, but it still does not restart the loop when the player types it in. I will continue looking for the problem. Thank you again!

Comment: @CoryAhapow If my answer worked, please select the checkmark next to my answer. It should turn green when you do so. Thanks!